# How test Vaadin Accordion tabs?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have created a Vaadin (7.4.3) accordion with a number of captions/tabs.

I need to be able to select a tab and check the contents within that tab.
However in the code below, even though the tab is found, the click() function
does not expand the tab and the contents of the tab remain unobtainable.

How can I check the contents of the tabs in an accordion?

Thank you...

```
        List<WebElement> tabList = findElements(By.className("v-accordion-item"));
        WebElement selectedTab = null;
        for (WebElement tab : tabList) {
            List<WebElement> captionElements = tab.findElements(By
         .className("v-captiontext");
            if (captionElements.size() > 0) {
                if (captionElements.get(0).getText().equals("Caption_of_tab_to_be_checked")) {
                    // this is run
                    selectedTab = tab;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        selectedTab.click(); // the accordion does not open this tab and contents are still hidden???
```

Comment: Did you verify that selectedTab wasn't `null`?

Comment: yes, selectedTab = com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_jvst9c2_4@15d0849

Comment: The code works for chrome (v.45) but NOT for firefox esr 38.2.1

Answer (score 2):

TabSheetElement

```
tabSheetElement=$(TabSheetElement.class).id(TAB_AUTOMATIC_EMAIL);
tabSheetElement.openTab(2);
```

the Same you can check for multiple Tabs by adding `click();` at last for example

> tabSheetElement.openTab(2).click();

Comment: @ankit suthar I know How to write answers but this is just the core i directly provided for Readers get Solution and start Working Immediately Rather than **Wasting time ..!!**

Comment: I didn't see that coming, but ok it's appreciable.

Comment: For that in deep you have to Refer VaadinTestbenchCases..!!